# Reset method for bufio.NewScanner?

Tags: go

Is there a way to reset the *Scanner (from bufio.NewScanner) or clear old tokens?
Unfortunately "func (b *Reader) Reset(r io.Reader)" does not work with *Scanner.

**Update/clarification:**
I want to resume with the newest data from os.Stdout when "time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)" ends and skip all data that could be read during that 30 seconds.

I am currently using a for loop as dirty workaround:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdout)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())

    if scanner.Text() == "abc" {
        //do something that takes a little time
        time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)

        // my dirty workaround:
        // skips all old tokens/inputs
        for skip := time.Now(); time.Since(skip).Seconds() < 10; {
            scanner.Scan()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to "reset" a `Scanner`? Please clarify.

Comment: If `bufio.Reader` does what you want, why not use that instead of `Scanner`? `Scanner`'s own docs state "Programs that need more control over error handling or large tokens, or must run sequential scans on a reader, should use bufio.Reader instead."

Comment: So basically you want to skip data that could be read during that 30 seconds?

Comment: @icza yes, that would be great.

Comment: @Adrian I have assumed that "Scanner" is the cleanest way to read from a Reader line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the long operation in a goroutine. Discard input while the goroutine is running.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdout)
var discard int32
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for scanner.Scan() {
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&discard) != 0 {
        continue
    }

    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())

    if scanner.Text() == "abc" {
        atomic.StoreInt32(&discard, 1)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            defer atomic.StoreInt32(&discard, 0)
            //do something that takes a little time
            time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
        }()
    }
}

wg.Wait() // wait for long process after EOF or error.
```

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. It is also easy to understand and clear for me as a beginner.

Comment: Upvoted, but if it's a long operation, the associated goroutine should likely be cancellable.

Comment: @PenelopeStevens That's fair :)

Comment: @PenelopeStevens Cancelation isn't needed. Once again, thank you for your help!